# Piping output of command to sed

Tags: io-redirection

How would i pipe results of a command to sed without using '>>' so it appends that output to file?
What i want is something like this

```
command | sed -i "${command output}" file
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish ?

Comment: @don_crissti append output of nmap command to end of file

Comment: `command | tee -a file` or `command >> file`?

Comment: yeah, this has been beaten to death...

Comment: I think you don't understand...i don't want to use >>

Comment: That's nonsense... There's a thing called `noclobber` if you're paranoid about accidentally overwriting files via redirection...

Comment: @don_crissti Still doesn't answer my question...

Comment: Your post is a typical example of a  [_XY question_](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/233676#233676). Explain what are you trying to accomplish _and why_.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
command | sed [sed commands] | tee -a FILE
```

Omitting the '`-i`' will use standard input for sed magic, the '`-a`' for `tee` will *a*ppend sed's output to FILE instead of overwriting when used without `-a`

Comment: I know this, but using >> is not recommended, as you can accidentally type > instead and overwrite the file.

Comment: That's your reason for not using `>>`? If you don't want to type `>` accidentally then watch what you type. If you're that worried, back up the file before writing it. Sed won't stop you from shooting yourself in the foot.

Comment: I'm having trouble getting `command | sed "${command output}" | tee -a FILE` to do anything, because `"${command output}"` is not defined. The entire thing is predicated on a misunderstanding of sed and shell variables and pipes. The answer could be improved by showing an explicit example demonstrating that sed really can be used in this way, and covers some use case which is not satisfied by simply `command | tee -a FILE`.